# Are or Were? Which linking verb would satisfy this sentence

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

> In 2003, around 80% of North America's population **(are/were)** urban area residents.

Is the whole sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: it's were. trust me.

Comment: Hi, Hexa, and welcome to English Language & Usage. At this site we encourage users to share any information they've uncovered in their own efforts to answer a question, to let potential answerers know what they've found out on their own and what remains unknown to them. Please consider adding such information to your question.

Comment: Auxiliary verbs : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb . What is "linking verb" ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_verb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 2003 is in the past, you should use the past tense *were* rather than the present tense *are*.

Comment: In 2003, around 80% of North America's population were urban area residents.

***
Could you suggest a good 'paraphrase' for this sentence?

Comment: Not true at all. In fact it is decidedly wrong if the entire context is written in [historical present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present).

Comment: @Hexa: we do not do ghostwriting here. We do not do paraphrases, we do not do proofreading. And why would you want us to paraphrase *your own* sentence? You know better than us what it means.